# JPA Hibernate uses @NotNull Annotation on Getter despite using @Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ddl

I have an Entity that uses

```
@Entity
@Table(
        indexes = {@Index(name="URL_PARAMETER_INDEX", unique = true, columnList = "urlParameter")}
)
@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)
public class EntityA extends UniqueIdEntity {

    // From @MappedSuperClass "UniqueIdEntity"
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "uuid")
    protected UUID id;

    @Column(name = "urlParameter", unique = true, nullable = true)
    private String urlParameter;

    ...

    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    public String getUrlParameter() {
        if(this.urlParameter == null) {
            this.urlParameter = this.calculateUrlParameter();
        }
        return urlParameter;
    }

}
```

While the field urlParameter can be null, on first access it is generated and the newly generated value is returned, thus the field may be null, but the getter will never return null.

However, JPA translates this into the following DDL command: `add column url_parameter varchar(255) not null` and when I remove the @NotNull annotation on the getter it generates the column as nullable.

What am I doing wrong? I already added the `@Access(value=AccessType.FIELD)` on every super class to make sure JPA/Hibernate are using the correct access type.

**How can I assure that the Column is nullable, while still having the @NotNull Annotation on my Getter?**

Comment: Set `@Column(..., nullable = false)`

Comment: I edited my question to make it more clear what I want to achieve. I want the database Column to be nullable, while still having the `@NotNull` Annotation on my Getter.

Comment: I am not sure why Hibernate behaves like it does. `@NotNull` is bean validation, not JPA. The proper solution in my opinion would be to split the class in a business class and a persistence class. Let the persistence class return a `null` value, do the Getter-magic in the business class. I would further suggest to not let Hibernate generate the schema and rather use a tool like [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/), which will also come in handy for schema updates.